# Adruino Yun's Linux environment not working

Tags: arduino-yun, linux

I was recently given an Arduino Yun board from my university. I am able to upload sketch to the board, and it seems to function properly. However, I am unable to see the Linux booting up. When I want to reset the WLAN, ressing the WLAN RST button does nothing at all, the WLAN LED doesn't even blink or light up. Pressing the YUN RST button also does nothing.

So I did some Googling and found out that I could upload the YunSerialTerminal to the Yun, so I did that. And when I am trying to monitor the Linux boot up from the serial monitor. Nothing is shown. I press the TUN RST button as taught by the Arduino website while monitoring the Serial Monitor, nothing shows. However, the RX button does blink whenever I press enter.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to re-flash the operating system. Unfortunately it's not a trivial task.

I had to do something similar with a Dragino shield (like a Yun on a shield) that uses the same OS and core chip. Instructions were scarce and hard to follow, plus I run Linux, so there's even less instructions. I worked it out, though, and wrote a tutorial [here](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/fixing-the-dragino-yun-board/).

While that is for Linux and the Dragino shield I am sure the basic principles are the same for the Yun - just make sure you get the right image file for your Yun (don't get the Dragino one I link to).

The main thing is to gain access to the boot manager (dr-boot, or whatever the Yun has), which means setting up a wired (ethernet) network and messing with UDP sockets (using `nc` in Linux - no idea what you can use in Windows).

I'm sure you can find a tutorial for fixing the Yun from Windows (or whatever OS you use) to help you get into the boot manager and upload a new OS image.

Comment: Warning use version 1.5.3. When you download the latest version 1.6.2 you also need to update the bootloader.